# Swift how to catch error from Set removeFirst?

Tags: swift, error-handling, swift5

I'm a Swift beginner (who isn't ...).

I simply want to catch the error caused by `removeFirst()`.

Example (the third `removeFirst()` causes an error) :

```
var sockets : Set<Int> = Set(1..<3)

print(sockets.removeFirst())
print(sockets.removeFirst())
print(sockets.removeFirst())
```

How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot [`catch`](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html) out-of-range errors but you can avoid them **before** they occur

```
var sockets = Set(1..<3)

if !sockets.isEmpty { print(sockets.removeFirst()) }
if !sockets.isEmpty { print(sockets.removeFirst()) }
if !sockets.isEmpty { print(sockets.removeFirst()) }
```

Comment: OK. So I don't have to look any further. `removeFirst() -> Element?` would be more Swift-like.

Comment: @user18451290 You can simply use `popFirst()` if won't crash your app and if the collection is empty it will return `nil`. `print(sockets.popFirst() ?? "isEmpty")`